# Unable to parse comma separated string amount. Originally with Currency symbol

Tags: java, swing, number-formatting, parseexception

I'm trying to convert a `String` money value which is comma-separated. It originally has a currency sign. In this case, the Peso sign.

[image]

What I did was to remove the Pesos sign first and get the value from column 2 of `JTable` which gave me a `String` value of `"212,312.00"` However when I tried to use `Double.valueOf("212,312.00")` or `Double.parseDouble("212,312.00")` it returned a `NumberFormatException` error.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: " 212,312.00"
```

This is my code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < feesJtbl.getRowCount(); x++) {
    String valueWithPesosSign = ((String) myModel.getValueAt(x, 1));
    String stringAmount = valueWithPesosSign.replaceAll("\\P{Print}", "");
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, stringAmount);
    doubleAmount = Double.parseDouble(stringAmount);
    totalOfTuition += doubleAmount;
}
```

Any suggestion? I tried 2 different ways of parsing it but it looks like the comma is what's causing the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use  [java.text.NumberFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
Number number = format.parse("212,312.00");
double d = number.doubleValue();
```

Note: This only works if the current default locale happens to use a comma as a decimal separator. Some locales use comma as a thousands separator, in which case "212,312.00" would parse to 212312.00 instead of throwing an error.

Or else, you may use `replaceAll` and remove the comma (**,**) from the number and parse the digits only.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I just have to add another `.replaceAll()` as `.replaceAll(",","")`; to get rid of the comma. Didn't get any exception error with parsing after adding another `replaceAll()`

```
for (int x = 0; x < feesJtbl.getRowCount(); x++) {
     String valueWithPesosSign = ((String) myModel.getValueAt(x, 1));
     String stringAmount = valueWithPesosSign.replaceAll("\\P{Print}", "").replaceAll(",","");

     doubleAmount = Double.parseDouble(stringAmount);
     totalOfTuition += doubleAmount;
}
```